# rails_admin customize view for new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using **rails_admin** and have also used custom action for one of my functionality.
My requirement is fetching data from some other website using mechanize gem and I am able to do this part.
Now I need to send that fetched data on new action of one of my model so that data can be prefilled in new form and I can directly submit that to save to database.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

The stuff that I worked around till now is:

**lib/rails_admin/mydata.rb**

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'

module Mydata
end

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Mydata < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :visible? do
          authorized?
        end

        register_instance_option :collection do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-plus'
        end

        register_instance_option :pjax? do
          false
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do 
        end
      end
     end
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/views/rails_admin/main/mydata.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag("/movies/mydata") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'movie[url]', nil, placeholder: 'Enter URL...' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Fetch' %>
<% end %>
```

**/app/controllers/movies_controller.rb**

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def mydata  
    m = Mechanize.new
    page = m.get(url_params[:url])
    puts page
    redirect_to "/admin/movie/new"
  end

  private

    def url_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:url)
    end

end
```

**/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'rails_admin', 'mydata.rb')
RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Mydata)

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    mydata
  end        
end
```

So, this is what I did till now.
My fetched data is in **page** variable (mydata action of movies_controller.rb).
I checked this by printing it on console.

Now I want this data to be filled in new form of movies controller or I need to create one more action for this form data to be filled.
How it could be done.
Please help.

Comment: which variable u r storing fetched data? and what page shows if you display that variable?

Comment: I have edited my question with code too.
My fetched data is in page variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add a POST and GET request in action so that form can be submitted add a line like

```
register_instance_option :http_methods do
      [:get, :post]
end
```

and restart rails to see effects!!
You can directly call the Mechanize class from Proc.new functionality in rails.